# Transfer epub from Android phone to Kobo reader

Tags: epub, kobo, android, download

Is it possible to transfer an epub from an Android phone to a Kobo reader not using the Kobo app?

For links, getpocket provides a way: I send the link to add@getpocket.com where I registered my email address and then I can synchronise under Articles on my Kobo reader via wifi.

Another way could be to use a server app for Android I could share my epub with and I could get the file to my Kobo reader via wifi.

Is either of these -- or some other method -- doable between an Android phone and a Kobo reader?

Comment: Why don't you try your own suggestions. Why do you want other suggestions? My own preference is never to use wifi. Things may also depend on whether your books have DRM,

Comment: I tried using the browser to go to my email. Although I could access my email, there was no way to download the ebook to Kobo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the book(s) have no DRM, this is what I do:

1. Connect your phone to your computer and move the epub onto your
   computer.
2. Import the epub into Calibre.
3. Connect your Kobo to your computer.
4. Use Calibre to load the epub onto your Kobo.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to transfer books from my android phone and my android tablet to my Kobo Libra wirelessly but I am sure it will work with any other Kobo however you do need to downloaded the (free) app HFS (Http File Server by vortexinfinitum) from the Play Store to your android device and give the app access / permission.

On opening the HFS app it gives you an address (which is the same address each time for that device).  Then, leaving the app open on your android device, open the Kobo web browser *** and type in the address from the HFS app as if it is a URL and click on GO.  Your Kobo now has access to your android device.  Just find the book you wish to transfer (mine can be found in my Downloads folder) and tap on it.  Kobo will then ask if you wish to download the file (which you do so continue) and once downloaded voila the book is now on your Kobo.  You can only transfer / download one book at a time but you do not need a computer to transfer the book from your android device to your Kobo.

I have actually saved the address from the HFS app as a Favourite in my Kobo web browser as it is the same address each time for that device.  Each device uses a different address so I have in fact two Kobo web browser Favourites; one for my phone and one for my tablet!

*** On the Kobo Libra to open the web browser from the home page click on More / Beta Features / Web Browser / Start.

Happy reading, Hilary

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a cable Micro USB to USB-C. You connect USB-C to your Android phone and Micro USB to your Kobo eReader and voilà!
Using any file explorer application on your phone, you can simply copy epub files directly to the eReader mass storage.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that Kobo does have a web browser under Settings/Beta Features. There I can log in to my gmail account and fetch the electronic book I send from my Android phone. So I do not need a desktop/notebook computer to do this.